# Drawing on an image before drawing on screen in XNA using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, image, xna

I'm programming a game in XNA, using VB.NET. I want to create an intro to the game that zooms in/out the whole screen and scaling each image to accomplish this is cumbersome at best. I like to be able to draw a lot of .PNG's (or parts of them) onto a whole image, to then be able to manipulate (scale, turn etc) that whole image, before drawing it with the spriteBatch. The examples I can find use something like:

```
dim bitmap as New Bitmap
```

or

```
dim image as New Image
```

but these codes highlights the "Bitmap" or "Image" as red, and I cannot use them. I'd be thankful for any help on this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've experimented with Petri Laarne's answer and finally come up with a workable code (most examples online are using C#, and doesn't explain the entire process). Trying to explain it here:

In Public Class Game1:

```
Private WithEvents graphics As GraphicsDeviceManager
Private WithEvents spriteBatch, spriteBatch2 As SpriteBatch
```

In Loadcontent:

```
Public render2 As RenderTarget2D
spriteBatch2 = New SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice)
spriteBatch = New SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice)
render2 = New RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, 1024, 768)
```

In Draw:

```
spriteBatch2.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(render2)
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black)
        srcRect = New Rectangle(440, 0, 440, 440) : destRect = New Rectangle(100, 335, 440, 440)
        spriteBatch2.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend) : spriteBatch2.Draw(introNEWMirrorDecos, destRect, srcRect, Color.White) : spriteBatch2.End()
        destRect = New Rectangle(300, 335, 440, 440)
        spriteBatch2.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend) : spriteBatch2.Draw(introNEWMirrorDecos, destRect, srcRect, Color.White) : spriteBatch2.End()
        spriteBatch2.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(Nothing)
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black)
        destRect = New Rectangle(512, 384, 1024, 768) : srcRect = New Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 768)
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend) : spriteBatch.Draw(render2, destRect, srcRect, Color.White, PI / 12, New Vector2(512, 384), SpriteEffects.None, 0) : spriteBatch.End()
```

This is an example code from the actual game that worked like it was intended: drawing 2 things on the alternate rendering image and then drawing them as one single image (in this case being able to rotate it by pi/12).

Any comments on how to do this differently or more efficient is appreciated, and thank's for the initial answer @Petri Laarne

Comment: That is correct. You can even use the same `SpriteBatch` instance, as long as you call `GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(...)` as in the current version. Additionally, if the scene drawn to the render target is static, you can skip redrawing it.

Comment: Aha I can use the same. What do you mean by static and how can I know? When am I redrawing it, you mean? @Petri Laarne

Comment: If the scene does not change, you don't need to redraw it every frame. You only need to redraw the back buffer (`Nothing` render target) every `Draw` call.

Comment: ah I see, so render2 stays the same unless I clear it or draw to it again. It does change in this instance however, but it can come in handy later on perhaps. Thank's for the help again, without people like you I'd get stuck in this project over and over so I'm truly greatful @Petri Laarne

Answer (score 1):

`SpriteBatch` works with XNA `Texture2D` objects, whereas `Bitmap` and `Image` are `System.Drawing` types. They do not work together.

You can create a new `RenderTarget2D`, set it as active using [`GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434434.aspx) and draw there using a `SpriteBatch`. You can then draw the stored render target to screen using a `SpriteBatch`, since render targets are a type of `Texture2D`.

Comment: Thank's for the answer. Okey, would you mind writing an example of this? I'm selftaught and fairly new to this so most of what you just wrote is greek to me.

Comment: forgot that you can do this. @Petri Laarne